# Is there an Intelligent Personal Assistant available in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center

I am new to Ubuntu and I was wondering if there was an [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_personal_assistant) like Cortana or Siri in the software center.

Comment: yes **jasper** is great https://jasperproject.github.io/

Comment: Someone could write a great answer from that :-)

Comment: Sirius looks interesting; I'm not sure how complete or up-to-date it is, though http://sirius.clarity-lab.org/sirius/

Comment: @TruSecAi please add your answer here.

Answer (score 5):

[Jasper](http://jasperproject.github.io/) is great software and open source, you can [build your own](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/) assistant by appending some apps / technologies or use software defaults, most of developers use on raspberry PI  to build their own system like **Amazon echo**, you can chose your suitable installation from [Here](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/).

Comment: That looks interesting, but it doesn't say on their website how to set it up

Comment: The hobbyist inside me loves the idea, but it hasn't seen a significant update in years.  The days of old monotone robot voices that can't pronounce anything right  being "cool" is a couple decades past.  If I can't impress people, then what's the point? ;-).  Seems like a barely living project that is far behind any other similar service out there.

Answer (score 5):

There's [Mycroft](https://mycroft.ai/) that's open sourced but is strictly marketed as for selling for living room, rather than adapting OS to user. I feel like this is a good measure as to how Linux compares to other OS, and AI would definitely be welcome as Linux is not at all user friendly by virtue of being "rich" in Open Source.

Answer (score -1):

Use your own google account to build an Actions On Google Project, which lets you access it. Come Herehttps://console.actions.google.com